# Jquery script not running ajax GET request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I've loaded jquery but as far as I can tell my script is not running, I don't believe its an issue with my ajax request, but rather with my loading of jquery? 
I'm not getting any relevant error messages and console.log is not running.

```
<script src = "jquery.js">

$(document).ready(function(){
 console.log('why wont my script run?')

 $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://blockchain.info/ticker',
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        window.alert('success',data)
    },
    error: function(error) {
        window.alert('error')
    }
```

});

});

Comment: Is it valid to have both `src` and code inside `script` tag? As far as I know it will only bring the data and ignore what is inside `script` tag.

Comment: Your `script` tag attributes are invalid. For example `application/json` expects JSON and not JavaScript. Along with this `src` is for loading external JavaScript files.

Comment: `onload="...", onload="..."` is not valid HTML; You can only have one definition of `onload` and, even if you could have multiple, using a comma is not the way to do it

Answer (score 0):

You don't use the `src` attribute plus a script together within a `<script>` tag.  It's one or the other.

If you use the `src` attribute then it needs to reference the .js file or the CDN.

The reason your variable isn't changing is because you need to make an AJAX call to your exchange rate API.  You will then need to extract that value from the HTTP response and then update your DOM.